# How to replace system beep with a pleasant sound in Debian

Tags: debian

How to replace system beep with a pleasant sound in Debian? I do not want to turn it off entirely as it signalizes some notification.

All I managed to found was just manuals to how to turn it off entirely, or "how to-s" for Ubuntu that is unfortunately not proper for Debian (or I did not manage to apply them at least).

Comment: The procedure will most likely be specific to the desktop environment you're using, so you'll need to identify that: Gnome, KDE or something else? Also, identifying the version of Debian you're using would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using pulseaudio, you should be able to set the system beep using the `module-x11-bell` module. In `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, put in:

```
load-sample-lazy x11-bell /path/to/sound/file
load-module module-x11-bell sample=x11-bell
```

and it should work!